# How to access object with req.body?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, mongoose

I would like to create a new survey and would like the user to enter their own question based on type of survey(Multiple Choice or True/False). I would like the user to enter the QuestionText but my schema is structured like this:

```
// create a question model
let questionModel = mongoose.Schema(
  {
    "MC": 
    {
        "QuestionText": String,
        "Options": [String]
    },
    "TF":
    {
        "QuestionText": String,
        "Options": Boolean
    }
  }
);


// create a survey model
let surveyModel = mongoose.Schema(
  {
    "Title": String,
    "Type": [String],
    "Questions": [questionModel],
    "Answered": { type: Number, default: 0 }, // how many times users answered
    "DateCreated": String,
    "Lifetime": Number // Survey expiry in seconds
  },
  {
    collection: "surveys",
  }
);
```

I am unsure of how to access the QuestionText string in the "MC" object through req.body.Questions. This is what I have right now. Can anyone help me out?

```
// POST route for processing Create Survey Page - CREATE
router.post("/create", (req, res, next) => {
  let newSurvey = Survey({
    Title: req.body.Title,
    Type: req.body.Type,
    Questions: req.body.Questions[0].MC.QuestionText,
  });

  Survey.create(newSurvey, (err, Survey) => {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
      res.end(err);
    } else {
      // refresh survey list
      res.redirect("/live-surveys");
    }
  });
});
```

```html
"Title": "Some Survey",
    "Type": ["MC"],
    "Questions": [{
        "MC": {
            "QuestionText": "Favorite Color?",
            "Options": ["red", "blue", "green", "yellow"]
        }
    }],
    "Answered": {
        "$numberInt": "0"
    },
    "DateCreated": "Date",
    "Lifetime": {
        "$numberInt": "20"
    }
```

Comment: can you add the JSON payload?

Comment: @sid Sure, I've added it

Comment: so whats the issue here? your code req.body.Questions[0].MC.QuestionText is correct if you're receiving the payload as an object and not array and if the questions array has 1st index as MC. can you elaborate more on the challenging part

Answer (score 1):

Take the result of `req.body` and parse it into `json` using `JSON.parse`, assigning what's returned to some variable.

That variable will now be an object that allows your access to the props within.